# BottomSheetDialogFragment with nested ScrollView

Tags: layout

I have a BottomSheetDialogFragment and a ScrollView inside. What I want to do is making it so pulling it up will make it big, and the next stroke will start scrolling. But currently, it already starts scrolling when I pull it up. How can I make this so scrolling is only enabled when it has already expanded?